# how to convert excel file to xml file in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Excel to XML using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900647/how-to-convert-excel-to-xml-using-java)

I have one file with me which is excel workbook that is a .xls file, it is having some 12 columns and 1000 rows, I want to convert that file to xml file so that the column header will become the tags for all rows?

I want to write this code in Java.

Comment: so you want us to write full code for you? how about 100$ per hour?

Comment: check out this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900647/how-to-convert-excel-to-xml-using-java

Comment: @jsn : I don't meant actually... Just said simply...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the Java API for Microsoft Documents](http://poi.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the jexcel api: http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/

> When reading a spreadsheet, the demo programs may be used "as is" to
>   convert Excel files to CSV and XML formats in a reasonable manner.
>
> java -jar jxl.jar -csv myspreadsheet.xls