# updating and deleting rows in excel in java using poi with xml approach

Tags: java

I have a requirement in project where I have to delete few rows from an existing excel(.xlsx) and I have to update few columns from database.

For example,if I have 10 rows in an excel,I have to delete 8 rows and update 2 columns of a remaining two rows from database.Finally my excel should have only two rows with updated values.

Please let me know if I can do this with the xml approach using poi in java.I know how to read using xml,but am not sure about updating and deleting from xml.please help me on this

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834971/removing-a-row-from-an-excel-sheet-with-apache-poi-hssf

Comment: That is using hssf,please let me know if I can do with xssf with xml approach

Comment: Why do you choose XML over XSSF?. If you are using SAX approach, i don't think it supports deleting of rows. Since the data is spread across multiple sheets (sheet.xml, styles.xml & sharedStrings.xml), it will be a difficult one to do.

Comment: This project was using .xls files earlier which used hssf .Now we are converting to support .xlsx format files because of ceratin memory issues.So only we chose xml approach.Could you please suggest me an efficient/memory optimized approach for deleting and updating the rows in excel?

Answer (score 0):

you can use "row.getCell().setCellValue()" for setting the values. and for deleting you can use "sheet.removeRow()"

Answer (score 0):

An example code. I try to follow SSCCE principle.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;


public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String filePath = "test.xls";
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        //update the 1st cell in 1st row  with a value.
        updateCell( sheet, 0, 0, 0, "modifedValue");
        //delete row 2;
        removeRow(sheet, 2);
    }

    public static void updateCell(HSSFSheet sheet,  int sheetNum, int rowNum, int cellNum, String value ){
        HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow( rowNum );
        HSSFCell cell = row.getCell( cellNum);
        cell.setCellValue( value );
    }


     public static void removeRow(HSSFSheet sheet, int rowIndex) {
         int lastRowNum=sheet.getLastRowNum();
         if(rowIndex>=0&&rowIndex<lastRowNum){
             sheet.shiftRows(rowIndex+1,lastRowNum, -1);
         }
         if(rowIndex==lastRowNum){
             HSSFRow removingRow=sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
             if(removingRow!=null){
                 sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
             }
         }
     }

}
```

more examples can be found in http://poi.apache.org/

The question that Karth mentioned is about the trap of remove row.
http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getRow(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row)

Using Apache poi, the remove row function would be like in [Removing a row from an Excel sheet with Apache POI HSSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834971/removing-a-row-from-an-excel-sheet-with-apache-poi-hssf)

```
/**
 * Remove a row by its index
 * @param sheet a Excel sheet
 * @param rowIndex a 0 based index of removing row
 */
    public static void removeRow(HSSFSheet sheet, int rowIndex) {
        int lastRowNum=sheet.getLastRowNum();
        if(rowIndex>=0&&rowIndex<lastRowNum){
            sheet.shiftRows(rowIndex+1,lastRowNum, -1);
        }
        if(rowIndex==lastRowNum){
            HSSFRow removingRow=sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
            if(removingRow!=null){
                sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How to convert between xml and execel. JExcel or POI. You can see the other question and answers here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900647/how-to-convert-excel-to-xml-using-java?rq=1