# Convert a complex xls to xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xls, jxl

I am trying to build an utility that shall convert a xls to xml.

Below excel as you can see is denormailzed, contains list of lists and contains multiple relationship with parent and child. It  contains child elements that repeat more than once in a parent element body. Few elements have more than one attribute and not necessary all attributes are present for the same element.

what kind of excel format do I have for such data that is easy to fill and easy to translate using java and supported libraries?

Which library will be best suited? I have toyed with the idea of using libraries like (jxl.jar, javax.xml.*) however all these coding practices need a particular excel format which is hard to decide for this complex xml.

Sample xml format is like below:

```
    <req-template type="Req" spell-check="true" min-posting-days="0" min-internal-lead-days="0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <template-name><![CDATA[Standard Requisition]]></template-name>
 <template-name lang="en_GB"><![CDATA[Standard Requisition]]></template-name>
  <template-desc><![CDATA[Standard Requisition]]></template-desc>
  <template-lastmodified>1/7/15 3:00 AM</template-lastmodified>
  <default-listing-layout-id><![CDATA[2]]></default-listing-layout-id>
  <field-definition id="id" type="text" required="false" custom="false">
  <field-label><![CDATA[Requisition ID]]></field-label>
  <field-label lang="en_GB"><![CDATA[Requisition ID]]></field-label>
  <field-description><![CDATA[Requisition Number]]></field-description>
  <field-description lang="en_GB"><![CDATA[Requisition Number]]></field-description>
  </field-definition>
  <field-definition id="status" type="picklist" required="true" custom="false">
  <field-label><![CDATA[Requition Status]]></field-label>
  <field-label lang="en_GB"><![CDATA[Requition Status]]></field-label>
  <field-description><![CDATA[For reporting purposes only.]]></field-description>
  <field-description lang="en_GB"><![CDATA[For reporting purposes only.]]></field-description>
    <picklist-id>reqStatus</picklist-id>
  </field-definition>
  <field-definition id="instrDescription" type="instruction" required="false" custom="true">
  <field-label mime-type="text-html"><![CDATA[<p><br><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="blue"><b>Information Inherited from Position</b></font></p>]]></field-label>
  <field-label mime-type="text-html" lang="en_GB"><![CDATA[<p><br><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="blue"><b>Information Inherited from Position</b></font></p>]]></field-label>
  </field-definition>
  <field-definition id="title" type="text" required="true" custom="false">
  <field-label><![CDATA[Internal Title]]></field-label>
  <field-label lang="en_GB"><![CDATA[Internal Title]]></field-label>
  <field-description><![CDATA[Internal  Title]]></field-description>
  <field-description lang="en_GB"><![CDATA[Internal Title]]></field-description>
  </field-definition>
  <field-definition id="extTitle" type="text" required="false" custom="false">
  <field-label><![CDATA[External Title]]></field-label>
  <field-label lang="en_GB"><![CDATA[External Title]]></field-label>
  <field-description><![CDATA[External Title]]></field-description>
  <field-description lang="en_GB"><![CDATA[External Title]]></field-description>
  </field-definition>
```

References:

[Sample program using javax.xml.* for normalized data](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076189/enterprise-java/book-excerpt--converting-xml-to-spreadsheet--and-vice-versa.html?page=3)

[Xml transformation using jaxb](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/)

[Converting xls to xml using jxl.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900647/how-to-convert-excel-to-xml-using-java)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Open Office is good at converting document types, and can be run as a headless server, so that effectively can become a document conversion service.

Comment: .xlsx is a zip with xml-s. Then you have half the work done. Mind it uses a shared-strings xml. The advantage is that you can tackle points that are not treated in some xls library.

Comment: thanks for the reply stewart and Joop. However,excel or open office doesnt support denormailsed data, list of lists and multiple relationship of elements with other elements. Any other way to approach this?